# Android - Send data to WCF Service hosted in Winforms

Tags: c#, android, wcf

I have been through the normal channels to try and solve this issue, but I can't seem to nail down how to send data correctly from my Android app to a WCF library hosted in my C# winforms app.

I have checked that the service is hosted properly using the WCFClientTest app provided by visual studio and everything is working on that end. 
When I call this line:
**androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);** it appears to hang in the Android app

I am using ksoap2 in an attempt to call into the WCF Service, with [this link](http://drclawx.wordpress.com/2011/06/24/77/) as a tutorial.

**Android Code**

```
private static final String METHOD_NAME = "Alive";
    private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
    private static final String SOAP_ACTION 
                               = "http://tempuri.org/IDeviceHealth/Alive";

    //10.0.2.2 is the ip address for the device simulator.
    private static final String URL = "http://192.168.1.8:8733/DeviceHealth/HealthService/mex"; 

    //SOAP must be  the same version as the webservice.
    private static final int SOAP_VERSION = SoapEnvelope.VER12;

public void OnClickGoBtn(View v)
    {
        try 
        {
         SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope
                                     = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SOAP_VERSION);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        Object result = envelope.getResponse();

        String resultData = result.toString();
        Log.d("WCF Response", resultData);          
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
          Log.d("WCF IO Error", e.toString());
        }
        catch (XmlPullParserException e) 
        {
            Log.d("XML Pull Error",e.toString());
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.d("General Exception", e.toString());
        }
    }
```

C# Server:

```
 <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MetadataBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <services>
      <service name="DeviceHealthService.DeviceHealth" behaviorConfiguration="MetadataBehavior">

        <endpoint address=""
                  binding="netTcpBinding"
                  contract="DeviceHealthService.IDeviceHealth"/>

        <endpoint address="mex"
                  binding="mexHttpBinding"
                  contract="IMetadataExchange"/>

        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:10001"/>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:10002"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>

      </service>
    </services>

public string Alive()
        {
            return "I am running";
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be doing this inside an AsyncTask, and not on the main thread!  From your post, it looks like you're doing this from the main thread.

Everything else about your code looks normal.  I typically use a timeout though, and I see you don't.

Another thing to note is that you are pointing your URL at "localhost", but your android device doesn't know what localhost is.  You should point at 10.0.2.2 instead.

If it helps, here's a utility method I use in one of my Android applications that consumes a SOAP based WCF service.  Please note that I always call this from within an AsyncTask, never on the main thread.

```
public static String invokeSoapWebservice(String method, Bundle properties, int timeout) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {

    String action = SOAP_ACTION + method;       

    System.out.println("Calling web method " + method);

    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, method);

    //Note - ORDER MATTERS HERE
    //If the web method takes employeeId, workSiteId, jobId in that order, 
    //they have to be added to the request in that order (what bullshit!)

    if(properties.containsKey("loginId")) {
        request.addProperty("loginId", properties.getInt("loginId"));
        System.out.println("loginId = " + properties.getInt("loginId"));
    }

    if(properties.containsKey("employeeId")) {
        request.addProperty("employeeId", properties.getInt("employeeId"));
        System.out.println("employeeId = " + properties.getInt("employeeId"));
    }

    if(properties.containsKey("workSiteId")) {
        request.addProperty("workSiteId", properties.getInt("workSiteId"));
        System.out.println("workSiteId = " + properties.getInt("workSiteId"));
    }

    if(properties.containsKey("jobId")) {
        request.addProperty("jobId", properties.getInt("jobId"));
        System.out.println("jobId = " + properties.getInt("jobId"));
    }

    if(properties.containsKey("laborDetailId")) {
        request.addProperty("laborDetailId", properties.getInt("laborDetailId"));
        System.out.println("laborDetailId = " + properties.getInt("laborDetailId"));
    }

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SOAP_VERSION);
    envelope.dotNet = true;
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL, timeout);       

    androidHttpTransport.call(action, envelope);
    Object result = envelope.getResponse();
    String resultData = "null response";
    if(result != null) {
        resultData = result.toString();
    }

    System.out.println("Result for web method " + method + ": " + resultData);

    return resultData;
}
```

Comment: I moved the code to an AsyncTask and when I call androidHttpTransport.call I get an error back:org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: unexpected type (position:END_DOCUMENT null@1:1 in java.io.InputStreamReader@40d30448) any suggestions on that? I am using version 2.1.2 of the ksoap2 library if that matters.

Comment: In my experience, when I've hit an XmlPullParserException, it's usually because there's an exception server-side, and the response is an error message that fails to parse properly.  If you are logging all exceptions for your WCF service, you should look there first.  If not, then I highly recommend that you do log all exceptions from your WCF service, with maybe log4net or nlog or something like that.  There's also an option in Web.Config to return exception details from your service, which you should probably do.

Comment: P.S. you are probably hitting a 404 response because you are pointing at "localhost" and from your android device it can't find anything at that URL.  The 404 response would result in an XMLPullParserException also.

Comment: I changed the SOAP parameters and URLs and I am now getting an Internal Server Error 500. The XML Pull Parser error appears to have been resolved and I am getting an IOException now.

Comment: That sounds like a server-side error.  You should definitely be logging errors server-side, and then you could just look at the log and see why your WCF service is hitting an exception.